# How can I make sure my server is connecting through my router?

Tags: webserver, routing, ifconfig, port-forwarding

I have a Ubuntu server with PHP, Apache2 and all of that setup and working on my LAN. Meaning from any computer connected to the same router I can connect to 10.0.0.3 (My server). I have setup my router to forward requests at port 80 to 10.0.0.3 but when I try to connect to my (router)IP address 69.244.36.144 I get a "Connection was reset" error. Any clues to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed it, turns out the link is working. It just fails to connect me from my LAN. (Meaning outside computers can see it but not ones on the same router)

Comment: We don't do SOLVED here, just post your solution as an answer when the system lets you so we can vote you up!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, turns out the link is working. It just fails to connect me from my LAN. (Meaning outside computers can see it but not ones on the same router)